# ¿Como interpretar java.lang.NullPointerException en java RMI?

Tags: java, poo

Les muestro el siguiente código y su error y después tratare de explicar la duda.

- **El proposito del programa:** hay un servidor remoto que notifica a los procesos locales cuando se activo el *SensorEntrada* (ingreso un vehículo al estacionamiento). Del lado local, se crea el *ClienteSensorEntrada* para suscribirse al *SensorEntrada* (que notifique cuando lleve el vehículo).

No estoy muy familiarizado con `rmi` y tengo poca experiencia en `java`, por lo que no sabría si el error es de semántica del lenguaje o de implementación en el paradigma distribuido.

Este es el código:

```
    package rmi_local;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.rmi.Naming;
    import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class RMI_Local {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {        
            System.out.println("-> Inicio del main()");
            ISensorEntrada objSensorEntrada = null;
            IClienteSensorEntrada objClienteSensorEntrada = null;        
            try {
                LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
                LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RMI_Local.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("-> Paso el Primer try-catch");
            try {
                System.out.println("-> Inicio del 2do  try-catch");
                objClienteSensorEntrada = new ClienteSensorEntrada();
                System.out.println("-> objClienteSensorEntrada = new ClienteSensorEntrada(); se ejecuto");
                Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/clienteSensorEntrada", objClienteSensorEntrada);
                System.out.println("-> metodo Naming.rebind() no se ejecuto");            
                objSensorEntrada = (ISensorEntrada) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/sensorEntrada");
                System.out.println("-> Fin del 2do  try-catch");            
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RMI_Local.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RMI_Local.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RMI_Local.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("-> Error en el Segundo try-catch");
            System.out.println(objClienteSensorEntrada.getClass().getName()+"-> La clase");
            try {        
              objSensorEntrada.Suscribirse(objClienteSensorEntrada);
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RMI_Local.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("-> Fin de main()");
        }    
    }
```

Esto da en la ejecución

```
    run:
    -> Inicio del main()
    -> Paso el Primer try-catch
    sep 09, 2019 9:33:51 PM rmi_local.RMI_Local main
    -> Inicio del 2do  try-catch
    GRAVE: null
    java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
            java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    -> objClienteSensorEntrada = new ClienteSensorEntrada(); se ejecuto
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:341)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
            at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:212)
            at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:152)
            at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:137)
            at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:203)
            at rmi_local.RMI_Local.main(RMI_Local.java:19)
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
            at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
            at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:345)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:330)
            ... 8 more

    -> Error en el Segundo try-catch
    sep 09, 2019 9:33:51 PM rmi_local.RMI_Local main
    GRAVE: null
    rmi_local.ClienteSensorEntrada-> La clase
    java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
            java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmi_local.IClienteSensorEntrada (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:421)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:272)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
            at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:379)
            at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
            at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
            at rmi_local.RMI_Local.main(RMI_Local.java:28)
    Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmi_local.IClienteSensorEntrada (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
            at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:411)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:272)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmi_local.IClienteSensorEntrada (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
            at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:556)
            at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
            at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
            at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:265)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
            ... 15 more

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at rmi_local.RMI_Local.main(RMI_Local.java:42)
    BUILD STOPPED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

la linea 42 tiene la instrucción

```
objSensorEntrada.Suscribirse(objClienteSensorEntrada);
```

en el ultimo bloque try-catch

La duda es, ¿por que me toma como puntero nulo si le estoy pasando como argumento el objeto instanciado?

Por otra parte, tampoco se ejecuta la linea de

```
System.out.println("-> metodo Naming.rebind() no se ejecuto");
```

Entiendo que ese metodo esta "publicando" el objeto en el registro local para poder ser invocado en forma remota.

Desde ya gracias

Comment: El problema es ya el primer error.. de ahi todo lo que sigue puede dar error al no hacer nada con el primer problema.. que es este: Port already in use: 1099;  el puerto ya esta siendo usado... tenes que usar otro puerto.. esto puede deberse a otra corrida fallida que dejo el puerto sin cerrar.

Comment: efectovamente era eso, del lado del servidor esta utilizando ese pueto. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentan, el problema puede venir del puerto que posiblemente se este usando para otra cosa.

Puedes probar a poner otro puerto y ver si se soluciona.

Otra alternativa sería averiguar que proceso o aplicación está utilizando dicho puerto y finalizarlo.

Abre tu símbolo de sistema (`CMD`) y escribe el siguiente comando:

```
netstat -a -o -n
```

Ó

```
tasklist
```

Verás una lista de proceso ejecutándose en tu equipo.

Ahora ejecuta el comando `taskkill /F /PID <numero PID a eliminar>` Eligiendo el PID del proceso que esté utilizando el puerto `1099`

Comment: me sirvio, gracias

Comment: @sal_defrutas me alegro que mi respuesta haya sido de utilidad. Por favor no olvides marcar como aceptada mi respuesta haciendo click en el check en gris al lado de esta :)